# How do I make the user input reflect in the new list created?

Tags: javascript

I have already created the function that allows the user to add a task, the problem I am having is how do I make the user input reflect on the newly created list, currently when I click to add the task, what the user typed, is not reflected in the new task.

In short, the user input does not show on the created task.

```
/************************************
 * creates an object of elements needed *
 ************************************/
 
 const elements = {
    form: document.querySelector("#new-task-form"),
    input: document.querySelector("#new-task-input"),
    list: document.querySelector("#tasks"),
    cal: document.querySelector("#calendar")
}

/****************************
 * Generates an ID for task *
 ****************************/

 const createId = () => `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}-${new Date().getTime()}`

/**********************************************
 * function that creates the HTML elements    *
 **********************************************/

 const createTask = () => {
    const id = createId()
    const task = elements.input.value;
    const date = elements.cal.value;

    if(!task && !date) return alert("Please fill in task and select date");
    if(!task) return alert("Please fill in task");
    if(!date) return alert("Please select date");

    const tasks = document.createElement("div");

    tasks.innerHTML = `
    <button class = "sort">Sort</button>
    <div class="task" data-id = "${id}">
        <div class="content">
            <input type ="checkbox" class="tick">
            <input type ="text" class = "text" id = "text" readonly>
            <label class = "due-date" for ="text">${date}</label>
            <input type ="date" class = "date" id = "date">
        </div>

        <div class = "actions">
            <button class="edit" data-id="${id}">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete" data-id="${id}">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
    elements.list.appendChild(tasks)
    listen()
    return tasks

}

function listen(){
    let allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.tick')
    allCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox =>{
        checkbox.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
            let parentElem=e.target.parentElement

            if(e.target.checked){
                parentElem.style.textDecoration = "line-through"
            }
            else{
                parentElem.style.textDecoration = "none"
            }
        });
    });
}


/**************************************************************
 * Event that listens for the edit, save and delete buttons    *
 **************************************************************/
elements.list.addEventListener('click',event => {
    const {target} = event;
    const {id} = target.dataset;
    const task = id ? document.querySelector(`[data-id="${id}"]`):null;  

    const type = {
        edit: event.target.classList.contains('edit'),
        delete: event.target.classList.contains('delete')
    }

    const isFromSaveLabel = target.innerText.toLowerCase() === 'save'

    //Checking to see if buttons are pressed

    if(task && type.edit && isFromSaveLabel){
        const text = task.querySelector('text')
        target.innerText = 'Edit'
        text.setAttribute('readonly','true')
        return
    };

    if(task && type.edit){
        const text = task.querySelector('text')
        target.innerText = 'save'
        text.removeAttribute('readonly')
        text.focus()
        return
    };

    if(task && type.delete){
        
        return
    }
    
});

/*******************************************************************
 * Submits the HTML elements to have the lists submitted and created*
 *******************************************************************/

 const submitHandler = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    createTask();
}

elements.form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
```

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/blaze92/seLvzd1h/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the text of task to the html string. I've added it to the readonly input.

```js
 const createTask = () => {
    const id = createId()
    const task = elements.input.value;
    const date = elements.cal.value;

    if(!task && !date) return alert("Please fill in task and select date");
    if(!task) return alert("Please fill in task");
    if(!date) return alert("Please select date");

    const tasks = document.createElement("div");

    tasks.innerHTML = `
    <button class = "sort">Sort</button>
    <div class="task" data-id = "${id}">
        <div class="content">
            <input type ="checkbox" class="tick">
            <input type ="text" class = "text" id = "text" value="${task}" readonly>
            <label class = "due-date" for ="text">${date}</label>
            <input type ="date" class = "date" id = "date">
        </div>

        <div class = "actions">
            <button class="edit" data-id="${id}">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete" data-id="${id}">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
    elements.list.appendChild(tasks)
    listen()
    return tasks

}
```